# Refresh page to get new SQL values

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, refresh

I have a method to update values in my SQL Database. This works fine. However, I need to refresh the page manually to show the new values. I want the page to update when the user changes the sql values. Here are my code so far:

```
<form action="userInfo.jsp" method="get">
 <fieldset>
  <table class="table text">
    <tr>
        <th>Name: </th>
         <td><%=user.getFirstName()%></td>
         <td> 
           <input class="closeEarlyForm form-control" placeholder="Enter New Name" type="text" name="first_name">   
           <button type="submit"  class="btn btn-primary closeEarlyForm" name="updateName">Update</button>
        </td>
    <tr/>
  </table>
 </fieldset>
</form>

if (request.getParameter("updateName") != null) {
    
    String name = request.getParameter("first_name");
    usersDAO.updateName(name, id);
    
}
```

The method "updateName() works fine, but I need to also refresh the page on submit. I prob need to implement some JS but I cant seem to find a way.

Comment: have you considered using an Ajax-like alternative? That wouldn't require to manually reload the page.

Answer (score 0):

I usually do something like that in JS.

get the data -> get my html into var X -> $('#myobjectid').html(X);

EDIT: if u need a bit of code to understand.

```
var X ='<table id=TableUser>';
X=X+'<thead>';
X=X+... you add your header + your data;
X=X+'</table>';
$('#IdOfFieldset').html(X);
$('#IdOfFieldset').trigger('create');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add `location.reload();` into your function to automatically reload you page.